# Backend API Security

Tags: ios, node.js, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a backend server which serves mobile apps both android and iOS.
Now I have SSL installed on the server so all requests made are secure.

Can you give me suggestions if I need to encrypt my sensitive info which is being sent to server as plain text for added security ?

I thought of have RSA public key in apps to encrypt the sensitive information for me.

Comment: Just use TLS/HTTPS

Comment: Make sure that the server public key for the TLS connection is verified (with a trust anchor) or directly pinned. There is nothing more you should do. Of course, if your API needs authentication, you need to authenticate the requests somehow.